# In a VAE, why do we use a sum operation when calculating KL divergence?

Tags: neural-networks, autoencoders

Following from a tensorflow guide on VAE's [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/generative/cvae#define_the_loss_function_and_the_optimizer), I notice the loss function sums over the latent space.

```
def log_normal_pdf(sample, mean, logvar, raxis=1):
  log2pi = tf.math.log(2. * np.pi)
  return tf.reduce_sum(-.5 * ((sample - mean) ** 2. * tf.exp(-logvar) + logvar + log2pi), axis=raxis)
```

Why do we take the sum and not the mean here? Wouldn't this make the scale of the loss dependent on how big our latent space is, coupling our learning rate and model parameters?

Comment: "Wouldn't this make the scale of the loss dependent on how big our latent space is...?" Why do you think this is the case?

Comment: If we're modelling with two latent dimensions, then the loss is calculated from the sum of the two. If we're modelling with 16, then loss is calculated from the sum of 16?

Comment: Ah, so `raxis` is over the latent dimension. Why would this be a problem, though? It's the formula for the Gaussian pdf.

Comment: "It's the formula for the Gaussian pdf" right that explains the source of it then. It's a problem because now our training parameters and model parameters are coupled. When training VAE's you sum ELBO with reconstruction error to calculate your total loss, and now the magnitude of ELBO will vary if we change the width of the model, which will change the balance between reconstruction error and a smooth latent space.

Comment: I could be wrong - but I think it doesn't really matter - the difference is the constant $1/n$ - you can make that up with learning rate - or a weight in front of a loss

Comment: "you sum ELBO with..." That's not quite correct—the ELBO is the difference of the reconstruction error and the KL div. from the prior. The KL div. is the expectation of a ratio; a larger latent space will grow both numerator and denominator.

Comment: Yes you're right. If you look at this section though, https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/generative/cvae#define_the_loss_function_and_the_optimizer, the actual implementation subtracts logpz from logqz_x so it will grow with the size of the latent space. @EdvBeq I guess the premise of my question was whether it was necessary to have to do those things to normalize the contribution of KL Divergence, or if it could just be handled by taking the average instead of sum.